# Connecting flight to Vilnius, LT via france ,Transit visa required?

Tags: france, transit-visas, air-france, lithuania, vilnius

Connecting flight to Vilnius, LT via france ,Is the Transit visa required to Hop in france for 10 hours ?

Comment: Note that, if you need to ask any more visa questions in the future, it's essential to state your nationality.

Comment: This is not a transit from a non-Schengen country to a non-Schengen country. Lithuania is in the Schengen area. You need a regular short-stay Schengen visa.

Comment: Lithuania is in the Schengen Zone. Assuming you do have a standard Schengen visa, you will do passport control _in France_, regardles of whether you stay in the airport or try for a few hours of tourism. And the flight from France to Vilnius will _not_ have passport control, as it is within Schengen.